# Random labels in Tic Tac Toe simulation

Tags: c#, arrays, random, label

I am working on a Tic Tac Toe simulator for a class and have run into an issue.

I created a 2-dimensional array to simulate the board and populate it with either 0 or 1 in all the boxes.

The issue I am having is getting those numbers to apply to the labels I have created (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, etcetera).

Is there a way that my nested `for` loops can have each element in the array apply to a new label?  I can't seem to find anything in my book or online about this.

Here is my related code:

```
private void newBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Random rand = new Random();
    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 3;


    int [,] board = new int[ROWS, COLS];


    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            board[row, col] = rand.Next(1);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where are these labels from? or where should they display?

Comment: On the form I have 9 labels in a 3 x 3 set up.  I need each number in the board array to match up with a label and set the label text to either X or O depending on if the random number is 0 or 1.

Comment: If you want a random 0 or 1, then `rand.Next(2)` is the ticket.  `rand.Next(1)` will always return `0`.

Comment: What are you using (Winforms, WPF, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

What are the names of the labels? I assumed below that the labels are Label0_0, Label0_1, Label1_1 and so on... This way you can find them using the `row` and `column` values.

You want to find the Label control on your form dynamically, because you don't know the name in advance while coding.

If you know the name in advance you just say: `label1.Text = "1";`.

But in your case, you are trying to find a particular control in each iteration of the loop. So you need to have a name for the labels so you can find them using `Form.Controls.Find(string, bool)` like this:

```
        var row = 4;
        var col = 6;
        var l = this.Controls.Find("Label" + row.ToString() + "_" + col.ToString(), false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
        if (l == null)
        {
            //problem... create label?
            l = new Label() { Text = "X or O" }; //the position of this need to be set (the default is 0,0)
            this.Controls.Add(l);
        }
        else
        {
            l.Text = "X or O";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `board` stores integers, which is an internal representation of your game state. You can create a `UniformGrid` that holds `Label` for your game GUI. The code below returns a grid based on your current board. You need to add this returned grid to your MainWindow (or whatever you use) to see it.

```
private UniformGrid fillLabels(int[,] board)
{
    int numRow = board.GetLength(0);
    int numCol = board.GetLength(1);
    UniformGrid g = new UniformGrid() { Rows = numRow, Columns = numCol };

    for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Content = (board[i, j] == 0) ? "O" : "X";
            Grid.SetRow(l, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(l, j);
            g.Children.Add(l);
        }
    }
    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not *re-create* (and *re-initializ*e) `Random` each time you need it: it makes generated sequences *skewed badly*:

```
private static Random s_Rand = new Random();
```

Try not implement algorithm in the button enent *directly*, it's a bad practice:

```
private void CreateField() { ... } 

private void newBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CreateField();
}
```

putting all together:

```
private static Random s_Rand = new Random();

private void ApplyLabelText(String name, String text, Control parent = null) {
  if (null == parent)
    parent = this;

  Label lb = parent as Label;

  if ((lb != null) && (String.Equals(name, lb.Name))) {
    lb.Text = text;

    return;
  }

  foreach(Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    ApplyLabelText(name, text, ctrl);
}

private void CreateField() { 
  for (Char row = 'a'; row <= 'c'; ++row)
    for (int col = 1; col <= 3; ++col)
      ApplyLabelText(row.ToString() + col.ToString(), s_Rand.Next(1) == 0 ? "O" : "X"); 
} 

private void newBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CreateField();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you skip the INTEGER board and go directly to a Label array?

You can then do the following to loop trough all of them:

```
Label[,] listOfLabels; // Do also initialize this.

foreach(Label current in listOfLabels)
{
   current.Text = _rand.Next(2) == 0 ? "0" : "X";
}
```